# Error message does not match my rake route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

my ruby on rails 3.0.3 app display following message :

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts"}
```

but in my rake route i have the following :

> cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts"}

I am trying to do a nested form where you are redirected back to the page with the form when the update attributes fails.

```
def confirmation
@cart=current_cart
respond_to do |format|
  if @cart.update_attributes(params[:cart])
    return
  else
    redirect_to :action=> "show"
  end
end
```

end

The app ask for address in the show cart and then display confirmation page with address. Both pages belong to cart.
The nested forms come from my address element. If i restpect the validates conditions of adress it works fine. I want to handle missing form info and other validates attributes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the redirect, you'll have to also send it a parameter for the show (basically, the ID).

Try this instead (looks cleaner too):

```
redirect_to cart_path(@cart)
```